# Querying flat table structure with EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I'm using EF (4.4) and have a flat table with `N` columns named `Value1` ... `ValueN`.

Based on another column (`ValueIndex`) I need to grab the three columns with `N` values of `ValueN-1`, `ValueN`, and `ValueN+1`

For example if `ValueIndex` is `3` I need to get `Value2`, `Value3`, and `Value4`.

*For the sake of simplicity assume `ValueIndex` is free from bounds issue, i.e. not `1` or `N` and that I have 7 `Value` columns.*

If this was in memory I would do (and probably will do) something like this:

```
table.Select(t =>
  new {
    ValueIndex = t.ValueIndex, 
    Values = new[] {
      Value1, Value2, Value3, Value4, Value5, Value6, Value7
    }
  })
.Select(t => 
  new[] {
    Values[ValueIndex-1], Values[ValueIndex], Values[ValueIndex+1]
  }
);
```

Unfortunately this won't work in EF due to the array indices being unsupported.

As a workaround I tried replacing the array indices with an indexer select:

```
.Select(t => 
  new[] {
    t.Values.Where((v, i) => i == t.ValueIndex-1).First(),
    t.Values.Where((v, i) => i == t.ValueIndex).First(),
    t.Values.Where((v, i) => i == t.ValueIndex+1).First(),
  }
);
```

But unfortunately that isn't supported either (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the `Where` method on the `t.Values` variable).

I don't especially want a gigantic switch statement in my code:

```
tables.Select(t => 
  new[] {
    t.ValueIndex == 2 ?
      new[] {
        t.Value1,
        t.Value2,
        t.Value3,
      }
    : t.ValueIndex == 3 ?
      new[] {
        t.Value2,
        t.Value3,
        t.Value4,
      }
    : // Etc..
  }
);
```

So is there any way to achieve the query I'm after using EF (i.e. convertible to SQL) in a manner other than a massive switch/case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework (and many ORMs) are designed for relational databases. In other situations (document stores, or key value stores), they tend to fall apart...

That said, if you Entity Framework is still the right tool here, think about how this would possibly be handled in SQL... It sounds sort of like a pivot to me.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ValueIndex = 1 THEN Value0 WHEN ValueIndex = 2 THEN Value1...... END,
   CASE WHEN ValueIndex = 1 THEN Value1 WHEN ValueIndex = 2 THEN Value2.... END,
   CASE When ValueIndex = 1 THEN Value2 WHEN ValueIndex = 2 THEN Value3..... END
FROM ....
```

So...can you build this in LINQ? Sure...

```
from t in in table
select new 
{
     ValueIndex = t.ValueIndex,
     First = t.ValueIndex == 1 ? t.Value0 : (t.ValueIndex == 2 ? t.Value1 : ....),
     Second = t.ValueIndex == 1 ? t.Value1 : (t.ValueIndex == 2 ? t.Value2 : ....),
     Third = t.ValueIndex == 1 ? t.Value2 : (t.ValueIndex == 2 ? t.Value3 : ....)
}
```

Kind of ugly though...

If you wanted to make it sustainable, you could build the expression tree above out dynamically fairly easily.

So you could have something like

```
public class Triplet
{
    public string Item1 { get; set; }
    public string Item2 { get; set; }
    public string Item3 { get; set; }
}

public static IQueryable<Triplet> GetTriplets(IQueryable<TableRow> source)
    {
        var lambda =
            Expression
             .Lambda<Func<TableRow, Triplet>>(Expression.MemberInit(
                Expression.New(typeof (Triplet)),
                     CreateMemberBind(-1),
                     CreateMemberBind(0),
                     CreateMemberBind(1)));

        return source.Select(lambda);
    }
```

Comment: I think this is about as good as it gets as I suspected. Thanks for answering.